# Code for creating string in a loop to report numbers

Tags: string, loops, input, while-loop, sum

I created a code that functions as it is supposed to. I determined the escape function to be `-1` for the user to exit the program and used `if/else` to only add the sum of positive integers.

I know that I have to save the numbers that pass the `if` statement (only positive numbers) and the only way that I can think of doing this is through a `String`.

Unfortunately, whenever I attempt to add a string as part of the `while` loop, it will print the statement over and over again when I only want a single line.

I'm also struggling to set the user input to a single line. I know it has everything to do with the `.nextLine()` command, but if I pull it outside the brackets (which I've attempted to do) then it reads as an error.

Actually, a source about conversion of `String`s to characters or inputs to `String`s would be very helpful as well. It's apparent that this is where a good portion of my understanding is lacking.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
  int userNum = 0;
  int sum = 0;

   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  String str3;

  System.out.print("Enter positive integers (to exit enter -1):\n ");

     //Loop for adding sum with exit -1
     while(userNum != -1){ 

           //condition to only calculate positive numbers user entered
           if(userNum > 0){
              //calculation of all positive numbers user entered
              sum += userNum;
              str3 = String.valueOf(userNum);}
              userNum = s.nextInt();
              }
      System.out.println("The values of the sum are: " + str3);
      System.out.println("The Sum: " + sum);
     }
}
```

I'm hoping for the user input to be printed,

> Enter positive integers (to exit enter -1): **_ _** ___//with the user
>   input in the same row.

And...
values from string to read out on same line, not multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `str` needs to be initialized as:

```
String str3 = "";
```

and in the loop, each entered number must be concatenated to `str`.

```
int userNum = 0;
int sum = 0;

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String str3 = "";

System.out.print("Enter positive integers (to exit enter -1):\n ");
while (userNum != -1) {
    userNum = s.nextInt();
    if (userNum > 0) {
        sum += userNum;
        str3 += " " + userNum;
    }
}
System.out.println("The values of the sum are: " + str3);
System.out.println("The Sum: " + sum);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did keep getting the message that I hadn't initiated the string and didn't know how to do that. I used this example to aid in my next two assignments ( a bit different, but similar issues) and it worked perfectly! Thank you once again!